# Boa práticas ao criar elementos com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Quando tenho necessidade de criar elementos no DOM através do jQuery, eu costumo utilizar a seguinte síntaxe:

```
$('<div>').addClass('minha-div').attr({id: 'id-da-div'});
```

Porém, o que geralmente vejo nos tutorias pela internet é um pouco diferente.
Geralmente é:

```
$('<div></div>').addClass('minha-div').attr({id: 'id-da-div'});
```

Ou:

```
$('<div id="id-da-div" class="minha-div"></div>');
```

- Gostaria de saber se, pelo fato de eu não fechar a div no primeiro exemplo, poderia haver algum problema (até hoje funcionou corretamente) e se isso é uma má prática.
- Eu devo criar os atributos pelas funções do jQuery (como no primeiro e segundo exemplo) ou devo "escrevê-lo" diretamente no argumento onde passo o seletor (terceiro exemplo)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você deve sim fechar a div:

> "To ensure cross-platform compatibility, the snippet must be well-formed. Tags that can contain other elements should be paired with a closing tag"
>   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Quanto a segunda pergunta, acho que tanto faz. Se não for constantes eu prefiro utilizar do primeiro jeito. Parece que o último é mais rápido (http://jsperf.com/jquery-element-creationyay/19)

Comment: obrigado! você tirou todas as minhas dúvidas.

Comment: Para a segunda pergunta, pessoalmente eu acho mais elegante e prático através de um JSON (dois primeiros exemplos) do que uma string gigante, não indentável e possivelmente de difícil interpretação.

Answer (score 7):

Você também pode utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
$('<div>', {
    id: 'minhaDiv',
    class: 'minhaClasse',
    'outro-atributo': 'meuValor'
}).appendTo('body');
```

Sempre uso assim, funciona perfeitamente!

Comment: Eu nunca havia usado essa sintaxe até uns meses atrás. Pessoalmente eu achei um pouco mais complicada do que quando já se tem o elemento criado no DOM, mas é questão de se acostumar.

Comment: Essa passagem de objetos no segundo parâmetro ficou bem melhor do que qualquer um dos meus exemplos. Assim que possível, vou refatorar os meus códigos :)

Comment: Muito bacana. Assim `$('<div></div>', {html: 'conteúdo da div'})` você escreve dentro dela!